# Block internet access for target applications

Tags: windows, internet, firewall

I need to block access of target applications to the internet on Windows 7 and Windows 10. What is the most simple util for that? I don't want to use a full featured firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maaybe you would like to consider sandboxie
(https://www.sandboxie.com/), which allows you to either virtualize or completely block access to resources like drive, internet etc.